# Using Eprint and arXiv papers in bib

Tags: bibliographies

With the following bib entry in `sample-base.bib` file

```
@Eprint{Radford16,
  author    = {A. Radford and L. Metz and S. Chintala},
  title     = {Unsupervised Representation Learning with Deep Convolutional Generative Adversarial Networks},
  year      = 2016,
  eid = {arXiv:1511.06434},
  archivePrefix = {arXiv},
  eprint = {1511.06434},
}
```

and the following headers

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
...
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sample-base}
\end{document}
```

I see this output which misses `arXiv` and the number.

```
[41] A. Radford, L. Metz, and S. Chintala. Unsupervised representation
learning with deep convolutional generative adversarial networks, 2016.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: I think the only good reason to use a publisher class like `IEEEtran` is if you want to submit your work to that publisher. In that case you probably also want to use their bibliography style (`\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`) and not `plain`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
@eprint{Radford16,
  author =       {A. Radford and L. Metz and S. Chintala},
  title =        {Unsupervised Representation Learning with Deep
                  Convolutional Generative Adversarial Networks},
  year =         2016,
  note =         "arXiv 1511.06434",
}
```

[image]